# belongs_to association error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model-associations

I have been trying for hours to create Items that `belongs_to` a Booth.  I have declared the following:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booth 
  belongs_to :category 
end
```

and

```
class Booth < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items 

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: {maximum: 25}
end
```

According to the ror documentation, this build method should work since the item belongs_to the booth:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

 def create
      @item = booth.build_item(item_params)

      if @item.save
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created product."
        redirect_to @item
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
```

However the error message says that `booth` is an undefined variable or method.  Shouldn't the association have defined the method? I've also tried `booth.items.build` and many other versions all of which have failed to recognize the association. I think I'm not fundamentally understanding this even after reading the docs many times. Can someone please help? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
def create
  @item = booth.build_item(item_params)
```

Assuming this method is in a controller, the problem is that `booth` isn't defined anywhere. It looks like this is in ItemsController (your question could be a lot more specific in this regard), so what is `booth` supposed to be?

Your code seems to assume that `booth` is an instance of Booth, in which case `booth.build_item` would initialize an Item object associated with it, but it doesn't work because you've never assigned anything to `booth`.

Where your confusion lies, I think, is in the difference between models and controllers. For example, if you had this in your Item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booth

  def get_booth_name
    booth.present? && booth.name # (1)
  end
end

# (2)
item = Item.find(123)
puts item.booth          # => #<Booth id: 456, name: "My booth!">
puts item.get_booth_name # => My booth!
```

...both (1) and (2) would work, because in both cases `booth` is the instance method `Item#booth`, which is defined by the `belongs_to :booth` association.

But ItemsController doesn't know much about Booth, and there is no `ItemsController#booth` method. ItemsController doesn't even know much about Item.

```
class ItemsController < ActionController::Base
  def some_method
    puts booth.name # (1) => NameError: undefined local variable or method `booth'...
  end

  def another_method
    # (2)
    item = Item.find(123)
    puts item.booth          # => #<Booth id: 456, name: "My booth!">
    puts item.get_booth_name # => My booth!

    # (3)
    booth = Booth.find(456)
    puts booth == item.booth  # => true
  end
end
```

This time, (1) raises an error because `booth` isn't a method that exists in ItemsController. (2) will work, however, because the instance of Item has a `booth` method. (3) also works, because we've retrieved the Booth from the database and assigned it to the variable `booth`.

(I'm assuming, in both of these examples, that an Item with `id` 123 exists, and that it's associated with a Booth with `id` 456.)

Comment: Thanks for a very thorough explanation.  It's helpful.  I edited the ? to show the controller.  If I'm understanding this correctly, I need to define some sort of user_booth method in the items controller.  Then I could use 'def create @item = user_booth.build_items(item_params)...'  This is what I'm trying now and it's not working.

Comment: Yeah, if you want access to a `booth` instance in your controller then you need code in your controller (or in ApplicationController, if you want it to be inherited by all of your controllers) that either gets a Booth instance from the database (`Booth.find...`) or initializes/creates one (`Booth.new/create`).

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to just use 

'@order = @customer.orders.create(order_date: Time.now)'

of course using

'@item = @booth.items.create(item_params)'

This is directly from the rails docs and what you should be able to do by creating associations.  Sorry to bother you, but can you please explain why this doesn't work even though it is the official documentation?  I feel like I've tried everything and nothing is working.

Comment: In those examples you still have to define the instance variables `@customer` and `@booth`, respectively. Although there's plenty of "magic" in Rails, there's no magic that makes those variables exist without your doing anything. If you've assigned an instance of `Booth` to `@booth`, then `@booth.items` will work fine. If you could point me to the passages in the docs you're referring to, I might be able to clear it up more.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Here is the link, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins, and it's actually #1, Why associations? where it explains it.  It does make it seem like magic...

Comment: Sorry, this is the correct link http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: The code there is not meant to be copy-and-pasted. It is example code isolated from its larger context, to succinctly illustrate specific concepts. When you see `@customer` you're meant to infer that code that isn't shown—code on "previous lines," if you will, that you would write as part of your own implementation—has already assigned a Customer object to `@customer`. Whether it's reasonable for the authors to expect you to have made that inference is debatable, and they might like to hear your feedback on that point.

Comment: To illustrate, take a look at [Action Controller Overview](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html). You'll see that in the larger examples, which show entire controllers from `class` to `end`, model instances never magically exist. In the [code under the Cookies heading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#cookies), for example, `@comment` doesn't exist automagically in CommentsContoller—it's initialized with `@comment = Comment.new`. This is always the case in Rails controllers.